# Range("A1:BC1").Select Selection.AutoFilter Field:="48", Criteria1:="> today ()-1" _ , Operator:=xlAnd

Tags: vba, excel

how to find date range greater than today's date

```
Range("A1:BC1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter Field:="48", Criteria1:="> today ()-1" _
    , Operator:=xlAnd
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The safer way when usinf `AutoFilter` with dates, in your case where you want to compare with dates greater than today, is to convert the date to `Double`. This way it won't be dependent on the format of the cells, use `Criteria` of `">" & CDbl(Date)`.

Also, your `AutoFilter` range consists of only 1 row ?

I used in the example below a random number of 1000. You should look for the LastRow in this range, and have you `AutoFilter` range dynamic.

```
Range("A1:BC1000").AutoFilter Field:=48, Criteria1:=">" & CDbl(Date)
```

**Note**: there's no need to use `Select` followed by `Selection`, you can `AutoFilter` the range directly.

Comment: date should be filter that is today +1

Comment: @Akshay  in which column do you have your dates ?

Comment: it is in 48 column